# Invalid verb conjugation מצות יאכל

Tags: grammar-dikduk, bo, grammatical-gender

In [Shemos 13:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.13.7), the verse uses the passive form מצות יאכל, where the subject is feminine plural but the verb is masculine singular.

A similar occurrence is in Pinchas for Pesach korbanos ([Bamidbar 28:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.28.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) and the only other location in Tanach is in [Yechezkel 45:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.45.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

What does this incompatibility mean, and why major grammarians like Rashi and ibn Ezra say nothing?

Comment: הכתב והקבלה שמות פרק יב: 
כבר מצאנו בג' מקומות מצות יֵאכל **והלשון נופל על האוכל לא על המצות** הנאכלים מדלא כתי' יאכלו בלשון רבים

Comment: הכתב והקבלה שמות פרק יג: 
 מצות יאכל. בא הפעל בלשון יחיד והשם בלשון רבים, וכן יותן מים על זרע, מי נדה לא זורק עליו, וכן יותן נחלתו הפעל לשון זכר והשם לשון נקבה, וכן המנחה אשר יעשה מאלה, ולא נמצא נשים יפות ורבים כאלה, ונתחבטו בזה המדקדקים, ולדעת רשד"ל כל הפעלים הסתמיים האלה הם באמת פעלים יוצאים אף אם הם בצורתם מקבלי הפעולה, ע"כ הפעל בא תמיד בלשון זכר ובלשון יחיד כי הוא חוזר לנושא שלא נזכר והוא הנזכר בל"א (מאן) ע' לעיל ע"פ ויושב את משה:

Comment: @mevaqesh he quotes multiple instances of masculine/feminine incongruence in subject and verb, but I did not understand the explanation; moreover, here there is a singular/plural discrepancy as well. Why don't you translate the last 2 sentences for the answer instead of a comment? I would be happy to upvote it. Thank you very much

Comment: Another grammatical oddity that occurs in the same pasuk is the usage of את. Onkelos translates it as ית which is the marker of the definite, direct object.  In what way is שבעת הימים a direct object and if so what verb is acting upon it?

Comment: @הבלשן The Talmud In *Pesachim* uses this oddity for *derush*

Comment: @הבלשן Likely the accusative of time (see [52.5-6](https://books.google.com/books?id=IiXVqyEkPKcC&pg=PA516)).

Comment: Is there a reason you're singling out מצות for this question?  "Mismatches" of gender and number occur frequently throughout Tanakh, both in verbs and in pronouns.

Comment: @magicker72 i never noticed one before where no rishonim would note this and there would not be a *drush* in the Talmud to explain it